# How adjust spaces between cluster bars in AmCharts JS

Tags: javascript, css, amcharts

I used to use AmCharts flash version and in the flash version I can easily create cluster column/bar charts like the image below.  As you can see the clustered bars have no space apart.  I am having trouble doing the same with the JS version of AmChart.
[image]

In the JS version here is what it looks like.

[image]

I tried playing around with the configuration but still cannot find a way to eliminate the space between the clustered bars.

Below is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>chart created with amCharts | amCharts</title>
<meta name="description" content="chart created using amCharts live editor" />

<!-- amCharts javascript sources -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>


<!-- amCharts javascript code -->
<script type="text/javascript">
AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv",
{
"type": "serial",
"categoryField": "category",
"backgroundColor": "#00000",
"fontSize": 11,
"color":"#ffffff",
"startDuration": 1,
"categoryAxis": {
"autoRotateAngle": -7.2,
"gridPosition": "start",
"labelRotation": -90,
"titleRotation": 0
},
"trendLines": [],
"graphs": [
{
"balloonText": "[[title]] of [[category]]:[[value]]",
"fillAlphas": 1,
"fillColors": "#ff0000",
"id": "AmGraph-1",
"title": "graph 1",
"title": "DIRECT",
"type": "column",
"valueField": "column-1"



},
{
"balloonText": "[[title]] of [[category]]:[[value]]",
"fillAlphas": 1,
"fillColors": "#008000",
"id": "AmGraph-2",
"title": "graph 2",
"title": "TRANSIT",
"type": "column",
"valueField": "column-2"

}
],
"guides": [],
"valueAxes": [
{
"id": "ValueAxis-1",
"title": "Axis title"
}
],
"allLabels": [],
"balloon": {},
"legend": {
"enabled": true,
"color": "#ffffff",
"position": "absolute",
"useGraphSettings": true


},
"titles": [
{
"id": "Title-1",
"size": 15,
"text": "DAILY REPORT OF TRAFFIC TYPE"
}
],
"dataProvider": [
{
"category": "2016-10-01",
"column-1": 22,
"column-2": 23
},
{
"category": "2016-10-02",
"column-1": 11,
"column-2": 13
},
{
"category": "2016-10-03",
"column-1": null,
"column-2": null
},
{
"category": "2016-10-04",
"column-1": null,
"column-2": null
},
{
"category": "2016-10-05",
"column-1": null,
"column-2": null
},
{
"category": "2016-10-06",
"column-1": null,
"column-2": null
},
{
"category": "2016-10-07",
"column-1": null,
"column-2": null
},
{
"category": "2016-10-08",
"column-1": null,
"column-2": null
},
{
"category": "2016-10-09",
"column-1": null,
"column-2": null
},
{
"category": "2016-10-10",
"column-1": null,
"column-2": null
},
{
"category": "2016-10-11",
"column-1": null,
"column-2": null
},
{
"category": "2016-10-12",
"column-1": null,
"column-2": null
},
{
"category": "2016-10-13",
"column-1": null,
"column-2": null
},
{
"category": "2016-10-14",
"column-1": null,
"column-2": null
},
{
"category": "2016-10-15",
"column-1": null,
"column-2": null
},
{
"category": "2016-10-16",
"column-1": null,
"column-2": null
},
{
"category": "2016-10-17",
"column-1": null,
"column-2": null
},
{
"category": "2016-10-18",
"column-1": null,
"column-2": null
},
{
"category": "2016-10-19",
"column-1": null,
"column-2": null
},
{
"category": "2016-10-20",
"column-1": null,
"column-2": null
},
{
"category": "2016-10-21",
"column-1": null,
"column-2": null
},
{
"category": "2016-10-22",
"column-1": null,
"column-2": null
},
{
"category": "2016-10-23",
"column-1": null,
"column-2": null
},
{
"category": "2016-10-24",
"column-1": null,
"column-2": null
},
{
"category": "2016-10-25",
"column-1": null,
"column-2": null
},
{
"category": "2016-10-26",
"column-1": null,
"column-2": null
},
{
"category": "2016-10-27",
"column-1": null,
"column-2": null
},
{
"category": "2016-10-28",
"column-1": null,
"column-2": null
},
{
"category": "2016-10-29",
"column-1": null,
"column-2": null
},
{
"category": "2016-10-30",
"column-1": null,
"column-2": null
}
]
}
);

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 400px; background-color: #222222;" ></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set `"columnSpacing":0` for the bars and they'll touch.

right at the top of your code, line 16 after "type": "serial", add a line of:

```
"columnSpacing": 0,
```

Here's a JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/1w3tbvyv/

Comment: I tried that before but what happens is that the 2nd bar of the 1st stack sticks to the 1st bar of the 2nd stack

Comment: Sorry, I updated my answer, you need columnSpacing, not width. Included a fiddle!

Comment: Thanks now I know that columnWidth is for single column charts spacing and columnSpacing is for clustered columns.